# how to hide the blank page in Tralier section report in Oracle Report?

Tags: oracle11g, oraclereports, reportbuilder

i have problem in the report section especially the Trailer Section. I have put the format trigger to hide the page when condition is the false. The condition has success but the blank page still appear in the page. how to make sure the page blank is not appear when my condition is false?. Anyone got the idea for this case?.

Comment: Check layout properties of trailer section layouts, and layouts before it.To be more specific, page brake parameters. you can eliminate trailer section by putting layout in back of Main Section. Try different layout positions, I am sure you will find solution.

Comment: but my problem is the trailer layout is landscape and the main section is potrait. did you got any idea than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, but I got the same problem now and here's the solution for others:

you have to use the `BLANKPAGES=NO` Parameter ([**documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/b32121/pbr_cla005.htm#RSPUB23798))